Obtaining a type from a base class
Suppose we have
class Derived : public Base1, public Base2, ..., public Base<Ts...>> {};

How to write a class that obtains the type std::tuple<Ts...> from Derived?  Perhaps Base needs to be passed as a template argument too, to specify which base class to search for.
Providing my concrete example here will be overwhelming to read.  Let's just say I need the Ts... in order to count how many of them satisfy a certain predicate.  This number is the constexpr int I need for each derived class, but I need to obtain the Ts... first.

If you add to Derived using tuple_t = std::tuple<Ts...>; then you can get it directly from the derived class.

@ NathanOliver  I though of that, but I have too many such derived classes and the Ts... are so long for each.  I'm looking for a solution that shortens the amount of code.  Also, to avoid updating code whenever the Ts... are changed.

Could you give some example of what your trying to do?  I wouldn't think my advice wouldn't add lot of code.  Each derived class gets that one extra line in it and then if you use a template you can just do typename T::tuple_t tup; and as long as the type has tuple_t it'll compile.

@ NathanOliver  Also, I want to avoid updating code whenever the Ts... are changed in any of the derived classes.  Your copy and paste solution would require that.

Could you provide specific and concrete examples?

I am curious what your use case is (I always try to avoid multiple inheritance from non-pure abstract base classes)

@prestokeys When you say Ts... changes, do you means like you change the name of the parameter or if the contents of Ts... changes?

@NathanOliver   Changing the contents of Ts...  Providing a concrete example here will be overwhelming to read.  Let's just say I need the Ts... in order to count how many of them satisfy a certain predicate.  This number is the constexpr int I need for each derived class, but I need to obtain the Ts... first.

You want specifically the Ts... from the single Base<Ts...> base class, not all the base classes?

@prestokeys Sorry, I'm not understanding.  Could you give an example where you show a concrete example class and what you tuple you expect to get from that concrete example?

Since you publically and unambiguously inherit from a Base<Ts...>, you can use template argument deduction to get the Ts...: https://godbolt.org/z/oWfe3z16j
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

namespace detail {
template<template<typename...> class Base, typename... Args> std::type_identity<std::tuple<Args...>> extract_base_args_impl(Base<Args...>*);
}

template<template<typename...> class Base, class Derived>
using extract_base_args_t = decltype(detail::extract_base_args_impl<Base>(static_cast<std::remove_cv_t<Derived>*>(nullptr)))::type;

template<template<typename...> class Base, class Derived>
struct extract_base_args {};

template<template<typename...> class Base, class Derived>
requires(requires { typename extract_base_args_t<Base, Derived>; })
struct extract_base_args<Base, Derived> {
    using type = extract_base_args_t<Base, Derived>;
};

Where you can make Base whatever template class you like.

not actually any. Only those with type arguments, which fortunately is alsmost any.
